# How can I count products in category

Tags: mysql, doctrine, nested

I have a table with categories in nested set model, I would like to take the categories with how many products they have. something like this

```
Categories-(6)
    Cars-(4)
      BMW-(2)
      Opel-(1)
      Mercedes-(1)
    Trucks-(2)
      Man-(1)
      Mercedes-(1)
```

I have two tables, `categories` and `types`

Categories:`id,name,level,lft,rgt`

Types:`id,category_id,name`

Now I'm able to list only the categories with this:

```
$categories = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Category')
  ->createQuery('c1')
  ->select('c1.id, c1.level, c1.name')
  ->innerJoin('c1.Category c2 ON ( c1.lft BETWEEN c2.lft AND c2.rgt )')
  ->andWhere(' c2.id = ?', $id)
  ->andWhere('c1.level > 0')
  ->andWhere('c1.level < c2.level+3')
  ->groupBy('c1.id')
  ->orderBy('c1.lft')
  ->execute();
```

Is there anyway to return the count like that one above?

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.name,table2.countcars
from categories as table1 right join 
     (select category_id,count(*) as countcars 
        from cars group by category_id) as table2 
  on table1.id=table2.category_id;
```

You'll get

```
    BMW-(2)
    Opel-(1)
    Mercedes-(1)
```

from above query

for Cars-(4)
you'll simply have to do this

```
select count(*) as numberOfCars from cars;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Maybe I didnt explain properly my question, Cars is not my root category, for example I have root cat "Categories" and in it > "Cars", "Bikes", "Boats" ect. And in this table "Cars" maybe I should named "Type" I can have all types boats, cars, trucks. If I count just table cars I'll get all. Thanks once for this answer. I'm going to edit my question